# How could I EOF `cat` through `netcat` without closing connection?

Tags: cat, netcat

I have run into a problem where I have a ncat server with the command `ncat -l [port] -k -c "cat > foo; cat > bar"`. When I connect to this server through netcat, it allows me to write to the file `foo`, and after that, `bar`. The problem is that when the client connecting wants to stop writing `foo` by sending a `^D`, it closes the client instead of moving on to writing to `bar`, so `bar` is never written to. How can I bypass this? What's an alternative to `cat` that allows me to quit with a command instead of an `EOF`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you want to do is transfer 2 files with only 1 connection, you will have to somehow use a marker to separate the files in the data stream, as end-of-file is a read of length 0 that netcat will use to close the socket.

`Control-D` may be what you can type in a terminal to signify end-of-file, but it does not generate a character, it terminates the read with a length of 0. There is no `Control-D` in the data stream.

To transfer 2 files simply, you could use an existing packaging command like `tar`. Use `nc -k -l 4458 -v -c 'tar xf - >&2'` as your receiver and `tar cf - foo bar` as your sender. (Since the filenames come from the sender you must trust the sender).

Alternatively, if your files are simple text you could introduce a special line to separate the 2 files. Eg at the sender `cat foo; echo bye; cat bar` and at the receiver something like

```
nc -k -l 4458 -v -c 'awk -v file=foo '\''/^bye$/{ file="bar";next }{print >file}'\'
```

This GNU awk script holds the first filename in variable `file`, then when it sees the "bye" line it changes to the second filename.

Comment: This is a very good answer, but I'm not sending files, I'm rather executing a remote script to a user that asks to make multiple file edits. Your AWK script is nice too, but I made my own bash script called catylist that is like a command oriented file editor and viewer. Your solution would have worked nicely if I got your post earlier.